# javascript image handling only in global variables?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm making a game for javascript/HTML canvas.

I'd like each player object to store a set of images, 
but it seems like image functions can only happen in global variables.

The following is one work-around that I've come up with:

```
    var image;

    function loadPic(a){
        image = new Image();
        image.src = a;
        return image;
    }
```

It's used like:

```
    pictures.push(loadPic(links[i]));
```

where links is an array of path strings.
Now, picture (a global array), can't be copied, or used for anything.

Am I doing something horribly wrong?
https://github.com/kaninepete/Javascript-Games/blob/images/MVP.js

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Image objects can only be referenced by global variables?  (It's not true.)

Comment: In my trial-and-error, trying to get this to work, this what I've concluded. I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I assume you meant to link to the code in your image branch https://github.com/kaninepete/Javascript-Games/tree/images (Download this rep and run MVP.html to actually try out the code)

Comment: in that file, you are resetting the global `pictures` array (first defined on line 31) inside the `Box` constructor (on line 88). is that intentional? seems like you're probably squashing the contents of that array whenever you create an instance. https://raw.github.com/kaninepete/Javascript-Games/images/MVP.js

Comment: @keeganwatkins I want to reset the contents every time, because each time, I am building an array for a different object (player, enemy, etc.) I would love to bypass needing the global "picture" at all, but nothing I've tried works.

Comment: you might try removing the global definition, and adding the `var` keyword inside the `Box` constructor to keep it local. this also has the benefit of making sure that each instance of `Box` keeps it's own personal array when assigned via `this.pics = pictures`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't see any image loading code in the github repo you linked to, so i couldn't see the source... as for @Pointy's comment above, here is the [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/E2KBQ/). notice that inside the closure, the variable `img` is local, i.e. not available in the global scope, and the code runs just fine.

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: I linked to the correct branch now, sorry.

I would love for line 90 to read:
        this.pics.push(loadPic(links[i]));

But going through the global "pictures" is the only way that images get displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error you describe, making `image` a local changes nothing, I tried IE 9, Firefox 5 and Chrome. I can however produce several other errors, the code only worked in Chrome before I fixed them.

You lack a doctag, preventing the canvas from working in Internet Explorer 9, put `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` at the top of your HTML document.
You fetch and try to set the innerHTML of a non-existing element: `$("score").innerHTML = score;`, either remove that or make the corresponding element.
`canvas.onmousedown = myDown;` only works in browsers that have short cut element access, you should use `$("canvas").onmousedown = myDown;`

Note that in the above code `$` is defined as shorthand for `document.getElementById`.

Comment: I've only been testing in chrome so far.
Thanks for the advice!